# Searching for ancestry records of family from Bosnia/Serbia/Former Yugoslavia

Tags: vital-records, yugoslavia, serbia, bosnia

My partner was born in Bosnia, as were his parents (migrated to Australia in the 90s).

Is there any site or anyone I can contact to find records of my partner's grandparents, great grandparents etc.?

I want to find his paternal/maternal ancestors.

Where would I find such information?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.

Answer (score 1):

I think a good starting point for you may be the [Getting Started with Bosnia and Herzegovina Research page of FamilySearch.org](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Bosnia_and_Herzegovina_Genealogy#Getting_Started_with_Bosnia_and_Herzegovina_Research) and in particular the [Bosnia and Herzegovina Beginner's Corner Getting Started](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Bosnia_and_Herzegovina_Beginner%27s_Corner_Getting_Started).

Once you have made a start, you will be in a position to ask more focused questions here about particular records for particular individuals that you are looking for.

When doing so be mindful of our Privacy Policy that applies to "anyone born in the last 100 years, whether they are believed to be deceased or not, and whether or not they have given their permission".

There is advice there on [**How to ask questions about ancestors born less than 100 years ago**](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).